# AWS Certificate Manager only works for root domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-certificate-manager

For `foo.com` (which I own via R53, and associated hosted zone).
Creating certificate `cert.foo.com` (and validating R53 records) works OK.

Now I create hosted zones `uw2.foo.com` and `ue1.foo.com`.
And then I create `cert.uw2.foo.com` and `cert.ue1.foo.com` in AWS Certificate Manager.  I also let AWS create the associated validating records, which are created in the correct hosted zones.

AWS never issues the cert, they remain pending until expiration.  Does anyone know what step I missed?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to recreate the cert for `foo.com` and add `*.foo.com` to the list of domains the cert applies to.